# jquery loop not working with php data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

well i am trying to assign values to my array in jquery 
its not working properly
if i do it without for loop like i did for 0th element its working fine
but if i put it in loop it goes undefined

```
var array1=<?php echo json_encode($array2)?>;
var array2=<?php echo json_encode($array1)?>;
var chartData = [
    {
    student:  array1[0] ,
    marks: array2[0]
        }
];
var x=<?php echo json_encode($tquiz) ?>;
for (var i=1;i <= x ;i++ )
{
    chartData[i]=[
                    {
                     student :array1[i],                        
                     marks:array2[i]
                    }
                 ]    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i=1;i <= x ;i++ )
{
    chartData[i]=[
                {student :array1[i],

                marks:array2[i]
              }
             ]

}
```

change to

```
for (var i=1;i <= x ;i++ )
{
    chartData.push({student :array1[i], marks:array2[i]});
}
```

By the way, i could refactor your finally code like this:

```
var array1=<?php echo json_encode($array2)?>;
var array2=<?php echo json_encode($array1)?>;
var x=<?php echo json_encode($tquiz) ?>;

var chartData = [];
for (var i=0;i <= x ;i++ ) {
    chartData.push({student :array1[i], marks:array2[i]});
}
```

Comment: ah thanx,i will never understand why every programing language come up with a new method for everything

Comment: There are two siple methods that help your working with arrays in JS (`push` & `pop`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach loop instead of for loop and here is problem in your for loop also:

It should be:

```
for (var i=1;i <= x.length ;i++ )
```

I recommend to you to use the foreach loop:

```
$.each( x, function( key, value ) {
```

Comment: umm no tquiz is a single value variable,loop is running the number of times it should run